# как увеличить размер numpy матрицы?

Tags: python, numpy

Задача : есть некая матрица размерности - (4,5,3). Мне нужно её расширить до (8,9,3) , заполнив новое место нулями . Как проще всего это сделать ?

Comment: related: [numpy - resize array filling with 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33256823/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без копирования данных не обойтись, поэтому можно просто создать новый массив нужного размера и записать данные:

```
new = np.zeros((8, 9, 3))
new[:4,:5,:3] = old
```

К примеру, если `old = np.arange(60).reshape((4,5,3))`, то:

```
>>> new[2]
array([[30., 31., 32.],
       [33., 34., 35.],
       [36., 37., 38.],
       [39., 40., 41.],
       [42., 43., 44.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

---

Можно явно скопировать и вызвать `resize()` метод:

```
new = old.copy()  # avoid ValueError: cannot resize this array: it does not own its data
new.resize((8, 9, 3))
```

В отличии от `numpy.resize()` *функции*, `resize()` *метод* нулями заполняет новые места. Распределение нулей другое (сперва все старые данные идут в Си-порядке в памяти, затем все нули):

```
>>> new[2]
array([[54, 55, 56],
       [57, 58, 59],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0]])
```

### Сравнение производительности

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: old = np.arange(60).reshape((4,5,3))
In [3]: %timeit new = np.concatenate((old, np.zeros_like(old))); new = np.concatenate((new, np.zeros((8, 4, 3))), axis=1)
13.9 µs ± 16.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [4]: %timeit new = np.zeros((8,9,3)); new[:4,:5,:3] = old
2.63 µs ± 168 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [5]: %timeit new = old.copy(); new.resize((8, 9, 3))
1.92 µs ± 15.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

`resize()` самый быстрый здесь.

Comment: `ndarray.resize` почему-то работает только с `refcheck=False`, при этом на оригинальном массиве (без копии); версия `numpy` 1.14.2

Comment: @mkkik: примеры в ответе я на той же версии запускал (numpy 1.14.2). Без вызова `copy()`, для `old.resize((8,9,3))` я получаю `ValueError`¶ Можно о numpy массивах думать как о куске/кусках памяти с метаданными, которые описывают: форму массива, тип элемента. Если массив единолично владеет памятью (никакие другие объекты, такие как другие view на неё не ссылаются), то простая реализация resize() может работать: просто `realloc()` вызвать и обнулить лишнее. `realloc()` может старую память выбросить, поэтому нельзя его использовать, если ссылки ещё другие есть (моё понимание).

Comment: Да, после перезапуска интерпретатора код стал работать. До этого была ошибка: `ValueError: cannot resize an array that references or is referenced by another array in this way.  Use the resize function`

Comment: @mkkik это вы copy() забыли (посмотрите на комментарий в ответе)

Comment: Как раз с копией не работало, поэтому попробовал с `refcheck`. Может, у меня были еще ссылки на этот массив, не знаю в чем причина.

Comment: @mkkik: я не могу представить обстоятельств (кроме нехватки памяти), когда это ломается, поэтому мне интересно, что значит "не работало"? Вот вы выполнили `new = old.copy(); new.resize((8, 9, 3))` и какую ошибку получаете?

Comment: Выше текст ошибки привел.

Comment: @mkkik: вы можете воспроизвести ошибку? Вот [пример, что работает](https://repl.it/@zed1/resize-numpy-array)

Comment: Воспроизвести ошибку не могу.

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю, можно ли одной командой это сделать, но как вариант расширять по каждой размерности.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.ones((4, 5, 3))

arr = np.concatenate((arr, np.zeros_like(arr)))
print(arr.shape) # -> (8, 5, 3)

arr = np.concatenate((arr, np.zeros((8, 4, 3))), axis=1)
print(arr.shape) # -> (8, 9, 3)
```

Comment: `concatenate()` подход выглядит [самым быстрым](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33256875/4279)