# Дополнение 4-мерной матрицы

Tags: python, list, матрицы

У меня есть 4-мерная матрица размера *n × n × n × n* заполненная числами. Мне надо дополнить её нулями до размера *m × m × m × m*. Подскажите, пожалуйста, **короткий** способ это сделать **без использования библиотек**.
Пример исходной матрицы размера *2 × 2 × 2 × 2*
`a = [[[[0, 1], [0, 0]], [[6, 0], [0, 0]]], [[[0, 0], [8, 3]], [[0, 0], [0, 9]]]]`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [как увеличить размер numpy матрицы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/819215/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-numpy-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b)

Comment: Я не пользуюсь numpy

Comment: А что вы используете - списки? Покажите какой-то код ваш

Comment: Я использую списки. Четырехмерный массив. Вот его пример для n = 2  
`a = [[[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]], [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Любопытная оказалась задачка. Конечно, с numpy было бы куда проще, а так пришлось поломать голову. Получился такой, довольно неказистый код, но вроде работает:

```
def ext(matr, m):
    ''' matr - исходная матрица (list),
        m - необходимый размер (int)
    '''
    def dims(x,m,d):
        if d:
            if len(x) < m:
                if d>1: x+=[[] for _ in range(m-len(x))]
                else: x+=[0] * (m-len(x))
            for i in x: dims(i,m,d-1)  # рекурсивно проходим все вложенные списки
        return x

    f = lambda x: 0 if not x or type(x)!=list else 1 + f(x[0])  # определяем измерения исходной матрицы
    return dims(matr,m,f(matr))

a = [[[[0, 1], [0, 0]], [[6, 0], [0, 0]]], [[[0, 0], [8, 3]], [[0, 0], [0, 9]]]]
ext(a, 3)  # расширяем матрицу 2х2х2х2 до размера 3х3х3х3
```

результат:

```
[[[[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[6, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]],
 [[[0, 0, 0], [8, 3, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 9, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]],
 [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Правда пока ждал ответ сам уже кое-как, но решил. Однако по памяти моё решение однозначно проигрывает, ибо в нём приходится создать дополнительный пустой массив нужного размера, и поочерёдно копировать элементы начального.